# Reorganizing and picking out elements of nested lists

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a list of lists. Each nested list contains either 4 or 5 elements (ID, Date, Time, Name, Note). I want to be able to pull out the nested list that contains the first time for each person on each day. Currently I have:

```
NestedList = [[100, 08/08/2012, 8:00, John Smith], [100, 08/09/2012, 9:20, John Smith], [100, 08/08/2012, 10:00, John Smith], ..., [131, 08/10/2012, 8:00, Jane Williams], [131, 08/12/2012, 22:00, Jane Willams], ... (thousands of entries with hundreds of people)]
```

I want to have something like this:

```
NewList = [[100, 8/08/2012, 8:00, John Smith], [100, 8/09/2012, 8:02, John Smith], ...,      [131, 8/08/2012, 8:00, Jane Williams], [131, 08/09/2012, 8:05, Jane Williams], ...]
```

The clock is set in 24 hour time rather than 12. I have already organized the list by ID number and then by date and time so I honestly just need the first entry from each person or ID number. I apologize if this is pretty basic but I wasn't able to find much that could help.

Comment: What are your data types? Is `8:00` a string, or something numeric? The snippets you're showing here can't be real code, since you don't have any quotation marks around any of the obvious strings (like the names) which makes it hard to judge the other items.

Comment: Your first code block has a "Jane Willams" and a "Jane Williams". Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get a single sublist for each date-name pair. This seems like a good use case for a dictionary: (date,name) is the key, and the earliest record for that pair is the value.

```
#uses an iterable `seq` to populate a dictionary.
#the function `keyFunc` will be called on each element of seq to generate keys.
#if two elements `a` and `b` have the same key, 
#`compFunc(a,b)` will return which element should belong in the dict.
def make_dict(seq, keyFunc, compFunc):
    d = {}
    for element in seq:
        key = keyFunc(element)
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = element
        else:
            d[key] = compFunc(d[key], element)
    return d

#I've put all your elements in quotes so that it's valid python. 
#You can use whatever types you prefer, 
#as long as the date and name can be used as a key, 
#and the time supports comparison.
NestedList = [
['100', '08/08/2012', '08:00', 'John Smith'], 
['100', '08/09/2012', '09:20', 'John Smith'], 
['100', '08/08/2012', '10:00', 'John Smith'], 
['131', '08/10/2012', '08:00', 'Jane Williams'], 
['131', '08/12/2012', '22:00', 'Jane Williams']
]

#the key is generated from the element's date and name
keyFunc = lambda x: (x[1], x[3])

#prefer the element with the smaller time
compFunc = lambda a,b: a if a[2] < b[2] else b

NewList = make_dict(NestedList, keyFunc, compFunc).values()
NewList.sort() #optional

print NewList
```

output:

```
[
['100', '08/08/2012', '08:00', 'John Smith'], 
['100', '08/09/2012', '09:20', 'John Smith'], 
['131', '08/10/2012', '08:00', 'Jane Williams'], 
['131', '08/12/2012', '22:00', 'Jane Williams']
]
```